# Transcendental, Algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra

I just want to know:

If a certain number is transcendental, call it $n$, is it safe to say that $n^2$ or that multiples of $n$ are are also transcendental?

For example, from $e$ is transcendental, can we deduce that $e^2$ is transcendental?

Comment: So, why does this question have many upvotes and is on the hot network questions?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is transcendental, and $P(x)$ is a non-constant polynomial with algebraic coefficients, then $P(\alpha)$ is transcendental.

In particular, $e^2$ is transcendental (let $P(x)=x^2$).

Comment: where can you find a proof of this theorem?

Comment: Suppose that $P(\alpha)$ is algebraic. Then $P(\alpha)$ is a root of a polynomial $Q(x)$ with algebraic coefficients. But then $F(x)=Q(P(x))$ is a polynomial with algebraic coefficients, and $F(\alpha)=0$. This is impossible, since $\alpha$ is transcendental, so is not the root of any non-zero polynomial with algebraic coefficients.

Comment: Good heavens, i should have seen that. Thank you!